# ADC bandwidth in excess of filter bandwidth

Tags: adc, filter, sampling

I am using a BPF of 5 to 300kHz on a pulsed input signal. Is there any benefit to digitizing at a rate significantly in excess of nyquist?

Comment: Yes the quantization s^N faster rate helps improve signal resolution by 2^-N and thus capture the signal more accurately if it is pure sine or sine+ harmonics

Comment: Good answer at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal/40261#40261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. Oversampling will always yield more information. Depending on how the signal is filtered digitally, oversampling can give more resolution to a signal or better timing.

In the case of a pulsed signal, if your sensing transitions or timing of rise/fall times, measuring time between pulses can be done more accurately.